# Kafka consumer returns no records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to makea small PoC with Kafka. However, when making the consumer in java, this consumer gets no messages. Even though when I fire up a kafka-console-consumer.sh with the same url/topic, I do get messages. Does anyone know what I might do wrong? This code is called by a GET API.

```
public List<KafkaTextMessage> receiveMessages() {
    log.info("Retrieving messages from kafka");
    val props = new Properties();
    // See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092");
    //props.put("client.id", "my-topic consumer");
    props.put("group.id", "test");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    ImmutableList.Builder<KafkaTextMessage> builder;
    try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props)) {
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TEXT_MESSAGE_TOPIC));
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        builder = ImmutableList.builder();
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            builder.add(new KafkaTextMessage(record.value()));
            log.info("We got at position: {} key:{} value: {}", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
            consumer.commitSync();
        }
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: what version of kafka you are using?

Comment: change this group.id and try again `props.put("group.id", "test");`

Comment: are you sure you subscribe to the right topic?

Comment: is the 100ms poll time enough?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have the same problem.  Gotta love silent failures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `auto.offset.reset=earliest` in your consumer properties. The default value is set to `latest`. I'm suggesting this because I see that your `group.id` is set to `test`, value that you may have already use in previous tests.