# Kafka Consumer empty records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, jaas, confluent-cloud

There are a lot of questions about this topic, however, this is NOT a duplicate question!

The problem I'm facing is that I tried to set up a SpringBoot project with Java 14 and Kafka 2.5.0 and my **Consumer returns an empty list of records**.
Most answers here indicate some forgotten properties, to [poll frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988037/kafks-consumer-poll-returns-no-data) or to set the [offset mode to earliest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706400/kafka-consumer-returns-no-records).

I can't see any *logical* difference from [docs.confluent.io](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/clients/consumer.html), eventhough my config-settings seem unconventional (see my setting of the [jaas.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756543/kafka-login-module-not-specified-in-jaas-config) in the snippet below).

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public KafkaConsumer<Long, MyClass> consumerConfigs() {
        Properties config = new Properties();

        config.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
        config.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "serviceName");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "confluent-cloud");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "serviceName");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, MyClass.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 300_000);

        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", ".\\src\\main\\resources\\jaas.conf");

        return new KafkaConsumer<>(config);
    }
}
```

This works however. I receive no exceptions (Kafka, or otherwise), and the connection is made.

```
// jaas.conf-file
KafkaClient {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
serviceName="serviceName"
username="username"
password="password";
};
```

Here is where I'm actually polling:

```
try {
            KafkaConsumer<Long, MyClass> consumer = kafkaConfig.consumerConfigs();
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(inputTopic));

            int count = 0;
            Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while (end - start < 900_000) { 
                // boolean would be set to true in production
                ConsumerRecords<Long, MyClass> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
                records.forEach(record -> {
                    MyOtherClass result = myOwnKafkaService.getSomethingFromRecord(record.key(), record.value());
                    System.out.println(result);
                });
               
                consumer.commitSync();

                System.out.println("visualize number of loops made: " + ++count);
                end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        } catch (KafkaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

I added the prints and other *clutter* in order to try and find the issue. I run my program in debug-mode and placed the breakpoint on this line:

```
MyOtherClass result = myOwnKafkaService.getSomethingFromRecord(record.key(), record.value());
```

As a result, I see a printed line with the count every second, as one would expect. But since my Consumer returns no records, it never enters the `forEach` and thus never triggers my breakpoint.

I can definitely see my topic in the cloud, with two partitions. Messages are generated in a steady stream, so I know I should be able to pick up something.

I know that it would take some time to connect to the cluster, but with current time being set at a quarter hour, I should receive at least something, right? As an alternative I tried switching the `consumer.subscribe()` to the `consumer.assign()` method were I specified my TopicPartition, setting the consumer to `consumer.seekToBeginning()`. It ran fine, but also returned nothing.

One other thing that's not found in the most common examples, is that I use my own classes. So instead of `KafkaConsumer<String, String>`, I implemented custom (de)serializers according to [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-sending-object-as-a-message).

Could it be my configuration settings? Something wrong with the poll timeout? The (de)serialization, or something else entirely? I genuinely can't pinpoint any reason as to why I'm getting zero records. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It wasn't anything you could determine from my posted question, nevertheless, I want to clarify a few things, should someone else find himself stuck with similair configurations.

1. verify that the received password is indeed the correct one. **Facepalm**

It was so, that I thought he was making a connection to the cluster, but instead my loop kept printing the count because the `.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000))` method is executed -> checks if he can connect within the given timeout -> moves on *returning zero records* if the connection failed. No error is thrown. Normally, after 2 seconds or so, a connection should've been made.

2. check your connection to the database.

You never want the application to stop, which is why I designed `myOwnKafkaService.getSomethingFromRecord(record.key(), record.value())` method to log all errors, but all exceptions are caught. It wasn't until I checked the logs that I realized my permissions to access the remote database weren't in order.

3. what's known as a TimeStamp, should be deserialized into java.util.Date

Wrongfully parsed it throws an exception, but my method returned `null`. As all remarks in this answer, this one also boils down to being inexperienced in such setups. You'll find the rectified classes below to serve as a working example (but not at all entirely best practice).

the KafkaConfig:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public KafkaConsumer<Long, MyClass> consumerConfigs() {
        Properties config = new Properties();

        config.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
        config.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "serviceName");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "confluent-cloud");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "serviceName");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, MyClass.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 100_000);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 300_000);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 300_000);

        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", ".\\src\\main\\resources\\jaas.conf");

        return new KafkaConsumer<>(config);
    }
}
```

body of the polling method:

```
            KafkaConsumer<Long, MyClass> consumer = kafkaConfig.consumerConfigs();
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(inputTopic));

            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<Long, MyClass> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
                records.forEach(record -> {
                    MyOtherClass result = myOwnKafkaService.getSomethingFromRecord(record.key(), record.value());
                    System.out.println(result);
                });
                consumer.commitSync();
            }
```

small example of MyClass with Deserializer:

```
@Data
@Slf4J
public class MyClass implements Deserializer<MyClass> {

    @JsonProperty("UNIQUE_KEY")
    private Long uniqueKey;
    @JsonProperty("EVENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private Date eventTimestamp;
    @JsonProperty("SOME_OTHER_FIELD")
    private String someOtherField;

@Override
    public MyClass deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyClass event = null;
        try {
            event = mapper
                    .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                    .readValue(bytes, MyClass.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Something went wrong during the deserialization of the MyClass: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return event;
    }
}
```

I hope this serves someone else in the future. I learned quite a bit from my setbacks and mistakes.